# Replacing character gives space

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have this code

```
from googlesearch import search
status2=input()
list = search(f'{status2} site:scpfoundation.net', num_results=6)
mylist = ' '.join(list).replace('%20','').split()
print(mylist)
```

For example status2 is "Таллоран" it will give us `http://scpfoundation.net/%20SCP-3999-J` and else urls.
Than, i remove `%20` and get `http://scpfoundation.net/ SCP-3999-J`, but i want to get `http://scpfoundation.net/SCP-3999-J`.
Why is it making an additional space?
I just want to remove %20 from every item from `list`

Comment: May be because you are joining by `' '`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `' '.join(list).replace('%20','').split()` to `''.join(list).replace('%20','').split()` so that you do not join the split list  using `' '`.